# Highcharts Angular navigator xAxis is not shrinking

Tags: angular, highcharts

I'm working on multiple graphs at the same time, these graphs must update when a use drag / resize the navigator. In my case, the navigator is moving correctly but, resizing does not work properly. If the navigator becomes bigger, there is no problem, only when the navigator gets smaller. For some reason, the other navigators won't update. See screenshot.

[enter image description here][Screen shot]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7a43k.png

The code I use for resizing the navigator is as follow:

```
let startNav = startDate - ((endDate - startDate) * 2);
let endNav = endDate + ((endDate - startDate) * 2);
this.chart.navigator.xAxis.setExtremes(startNav, endNav);
```

The variable (this.)chart is the main chart object in my view.

```
  chartOptions: Highcharts.Options = {
chart: {
  zoomType: 'x',
  type: "spline",
  panKey: 'shift',
},
title: {
  text: ""
},
subtitle: {
  text: ""
},
xAxis: {
  type: 'datetime',
  dateTimeLabelFormats: {
    year: '%I:%M:%S %p',
    month: '%I:%M:%S %p',
    day: '%I:%M:%S %p'
  }, title: {
    text: 'Tijd'
  },
  plotBands: []
},
yAxis: [{
  labels: {
    format: '{value} uren',
  },
  title: {
    text: 'lorem ipsum',
  },
  opposite: false
},
{
  gridLineWidth: 0,
  title: {
    text: 'lorem ipsum',
  },
  labels: {
    format: '{value} mm',
  },
  opposite: true
}],
tooltip: {
  valueSuffix: "",
  shared: true
},
credits: {
  enabled: false
},
navigator: {
  enabled: true,
  series: [{}],
     
},
series: [],
```

};

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should update the main axis and the navigator axis follows the main one.

```
chart.xAxis[0].setExtremes(10, undefined);
```

**Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/8vubh7zq/**